# How to store while loop results in 2 arrays depending on post type in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

My while loop is getting 2 different custom post types.  I want them to be displayed as follows:

**My Custom Posts 1**

custom post id1

custom post id2

custom post id3

**My Custom Posts 2**

custom post id4

custom post id5

custom post id6

In order to get that second heading in though, I need to break out of the while loop otherwise it'll run it for every post.  So I was thinking if I run the while loop and store each item in an array based on it's custom posts type.  So if custom posts type 1 store in array 1, if custom post type 2 store in array 2.  I'd then do a foreach loop for each array so I could put my heading before.

Does this sound the most efficient way?  Also, how do I get the array contents, I mean I'm not sure what is stored.  I know using wp function the_title(), I can get the title of the post.  Would this work using the array i.e.

```
foreach ($customPosts1 as $customPost1)  {
    the_title();
    the_content()
}
```

I also need to know how to check it's post type and what I actually store in the array.  i.e. array_push($customPosts1,?)

Comment: ok, no one is answering, so can anyone just tell me what object the while loop outputs so I know what to push into my array?

Comment: solved it, will answer question when I'm allowed

Answer (score 2):

Solved it, it's really quite simple:

```
 <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

                        if(get_post_type($post)=='offered'){

                            array_push($offeredItems, $post);

                        }elseif(get_post_type($post)=='wanted'){

                            array_push($wantedItems, $post);
                        }


                ?>
```